# Wordpress Php file Load

Tags: wordpress

How can i load php file in the body part a wordpress blog.any built in method for that( like wp_head,wp_footer and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding it to index.php file will add it to every page. Is that what you are lookin for?